# Make card dimmer. (ant design)

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, frontend, antd

I am trying to modify the style of the CARD component in Ant Design component library to make the whole card dimmer based on wether the object is active or not. I already have the active variable available to me, but I cannot find a css or component property that allows me to do this.

Any help here, this is my first main front end project and I am mainly a embedded developer and back end dev.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

You can style the card with the `headStyle` and `bodyStyle` props. Here's a simplified example

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-nash-rpijp

```
const App = props => {
  const cards = [
    {
      title: "Card Title",
      available: true
    },
    {
      title: "Another Card",
      available: false
    },
    {
      title: "Last Card Title",
      available: true
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div style={{ background: "#ECECEC", padding: "30px" }}>
      {cards &&
        cards.map(card => (
          <Card
            title={card.title}
            bordered={false}
            headStyle={{ color: card.available ? "#000" : "#d2d2d2" }}
            bodyStyle={{ color: card.available ? "#000" : "#d2d2d2" }}
            className="card"
          >
            <p>Card content</p>
            <p>Card content</p>
            <p>Card content</p>
          </Card>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```